# Jquery doesn't update an attribute as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC App and on one of my pages as part of the display I will render one of two partials based on a user selection of a radio button. This bit all works ok, but I have a button on the main form where I need to set/reset values that will be passed to my controller based on the user selection. The button is declared on my main form as:

```
@Html.GlobalModalAuthorizeButton("Upload Document", "Upload", "Documents", new { serviceUserId = Model.ServiceUser.Id, folderId = Model.CurrentFolderId, viewType = Model.ViewTypes.ToString() }, new { @class = "icon upload btn-primary" })
```

when this page is initially rendered the viewtype is set to the default view that the user is initially presented with. when the user changes the view the viewtype doesn't seem to get updated. So from the partial that has been loaded I try to set the value to the correct value. Using the Chrome browsers Developer tools if I do the following:

```
 $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find($('.upload')).attr('data-url').replace('FileView', 'TreeView');
```

it returns in the console window the value I want (idea is that i set the value on the button before the user presses it). The trouble is the above doesn't really seem to have changed the data-url attribute on the button so consequently when the controller is hit, 'FileView' is still passed through.

Comment: $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find($('.upload')).attr('data-url', 'TreeView');

Try this, if you want to change the attribute to `TreeView`.

Comment: Do you want the value to be TreeView instead of FileView? @Mike was faster, that's the answer!

Comment: Mike is right, but in case it wasn't clear: `.attr` doesn't give you a reference to the value on the element, it just gives you the current value. Unless you're doing a straight overwrite as he suggests you'll need to read the value, modify it and then write it back again. As an aside, can you come up with a better way of doing the many-parents thing? e.g. put a class on the one you're looking for and do a single .parent call looking for that?

Comment: @Mike The full attribute has : `/ServiceUser/Documents/Upload?serviceUserId=21&viewType=FileView"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For full attribute:

```
var new_attr = "/ServiceUser/Documents/Upload?serviceUserId=21&viewType=FileView";

$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find($('.upload')).attr('data-url', new_attr);
```

Or, as @Rup already suggested, you should first get the original attribute value, modify that using `replace` method and then reassign the new_attr.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery got a special method to read and write data attributes:

```
var uploadButton = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.upload');
var currentUrl = uploadButton.data('url');
uploadButton.data('url', currentUrl.replace('FileView', 'TreeView'));
```

Comment: Isn't it so that we can get values using `data` methods, but can't set it ( can set only once, not again ) ?

Comment: Thanks for replying and for the demo :)